# Unified memory and struct with arrays

Tags: cuda, unified-memory

I have a big Struct of Arrays of Structs on CUDA, that is constant and read only for my application. A quite simplified example would be

```
struct Graph{
    Node * nodes;
    int nNode;
}
struct Node{
   int* pos;
   int nPos;
}
```

My kernels would need to navigate this graph and query it. As you know, copying this struct to GPU memory with `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` is just lots of code, that unified memory is supposed to remove the need of.

In my code, I generated the graph in CPU and then, for testing, I designed the following kernel

```
__global__ void testKernel(const Graph graph,int * d_res){
    d_res[0]=graph.nNode;


};
```

being called as:

```
// using malloc for testing to make sure I know what I am doing
int * d_res,* h_res;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_res,sizeof(int));
h_res=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

testKernel<<<1,1>>>(graph,d_res);

gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_res,d_res,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

with the error checks [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).

When I use the `testKernel` as is shown, it works fine, but if I change the kernel to:

```
__global__ void testKernel(const Graph graph,int * d_res){
    d_res[0]=graph.nodes[0].nPos;

};
```

I get illegal memory access errors.

**Is this because the unified memory does not handle this type of data correctly?
Is there a way to make sure I can avoid writing all the explicit copies to GPU memory?**

---

Full MCVE:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>
typedef struct node{
    int* pos;
    int nPos;
}Node;
typedef struct Graph{
    Node * nodes;
    int nNode;
}Graph;


#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

__global__ void testKernel(const Graph graph, int * d_res){
    d_res[0] = graph.nNode;
    // d_res[0]=graph.nodes[0].nPos; // Not working

};



int main(void){

    // fake data, this comes from another process
     Graph graph;
    graph.nodes = (Node*)malloc(2*sizeof(Node));
    graph.nNode = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){


    // They can have different sizes in the original code
    graph.nodes[i].pos = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    graph.nodes[i].pos[0] = 0;
    graph.nodes[i].pos[1] = 1;
    graph.nodes[i].pos[2] = 2;

    graph.nodes[i].nPos = 3;

}



printf("%d\n", graph.nNode); // Change to the kernel variable for comparison
int * d_res, *h_res;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_res, sizeof(int));
h_res = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
testKernel << <1, 1 >> >(graph, d_res);
gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_res, d_res, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

printf("%d", h_res[0]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to provide a [mcve]   My guess would be it is coming about due to dereference of the `nodes` pointer inside `graph`, but you've provided no description of how you constructed `graph`.  Rather than try to address this one point, I suggest you provide a [mcve]  It is expected for a question like this, see item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @RobertCrovella You are completely right. Here it is.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of using unified (i.e. managed) memory in your code.  Perhaps you are confused about what [CUDA unified memory](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd) is.  There are also CUDA UM sample codes you can study as well as many questions about it here on the `cuda` tag.  Leaving that aside, your code is attempting to dereference a host pointer (provided by `malloc`) in device code.  That is a basic CUDA no-no, and the proximal reason for the error you are observing.

Comment: @RobertCrovella ah, I might have misunderstood the example (here)[https://devblogs.nvidia.com/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/]. Most of the samples I have seen *create* the memory as UM (as in the linked doc `cudaMallocManaged`), then fill it with stuff.  I haven't found an example where I already have a host structure as the one shown (generated by another process, with no control on it, on C) and I want to pass that to CUDA. I am bad at google or I can not do that?

Comment: @RobertCrovella to add to my misunderstanding (what am I missing here?), in the docs (K.1.6), it says that UM is what allows you to do: `int *data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
kernel<<<grid, block>>>(data);`, I assume for later derreferencing it. Or am I mixing things?

Comment: `in the docs (K.1.6)...`  Read that entire section K.1.6.  To the very last sentence/line.  The use of a host allocator (e.g. `malloc`) directly as a "managed" allocator depends on ATS support.  The last sentence of the first paragraph in section K.1.6 states "An application can query whether the device supports coherently accessing pageable memory via ATS by checking the new `pageableMemoryAccessUsesHostPageTables` property."  Did you check that property?  (hint: this feature is not supported in your system).

Comment: @RobertCrovella good hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't using CUDA unified memory.  UM is not "automatic" in any way.  It requires specific programming steps to take advantage of it and it has specific system requirements.

All of this is covered in the [UM section of the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd).

> Is there a way to make sure I can avoid writing all the explicit copies to GPU memory?

Proper use of UM should allow this.  Here is a fully worked example.  The only thing I have done is mechanically convert your `malloc` operations in host code to equivalent `cudaMallocManaged` operations.

```
$ cat t1389.cu
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node{
    int* pos;
    int nPos;
}Node;
typedef struct Graph{
    Node * nodes;
    int nNode;
}Graph;


#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

__global__ void testKernel(const Graph graph, int * d_res){
    d_res[0] = graph.nNode;
     d_res[0]=graph.nodes[0].nPos; // Not working

};



int main(void){

    // fake data, this comes from another process
     Graph graph;
    cudaMallocManaged(&(graph.nodes), 2*sizeof(Node));
    graph.nNode = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){


    // They can have different sizes in the original code
    cudaMallocManaged(&(graph.nodes[i].pos), 3 * sizeof(int));
    graph.nodes[i].pos[0] = 0;
    graph.nodes[i].pos[1] = 1;
    graph.nodes[i].pos[2] = 2;

    graph.nodes[i].nPos = 3;

}



printf("%d\n", graph.nNode); // Change to the kernel variable for comparison
int * d_res, *h_res;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_res, sizeof(int));
h_res = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
testKernel << <1, 1 >> >(graph, d_res);
gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_res, d_res, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

printf("%d", h_res[0]);
return 0;
}
$ nvcc t1389.cu -o t1389
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1389
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
2
3========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

UM has a number of system requirements that are documented.  I'm not going to try to recite them all here.  Primarily you need a cc3.0 or higher GPU.  Your MCVE did not include any standard error checking, and I didn't try to add it.  But if you still have problems with this code, be sure to use proper CUDA error checking and run it with `cuda-memcheck`.

If your entire data structure, including embedded pointers, is allocated using ordinary host allocators, and you have no control over that, then you won't be able to use it directly in a UM regime, without doing some sort of involved copying.  The exception here would be on an IBM Power9 system as mentioned in section K.1.6 of the above linked programming guide section.

Before attempting to use a host allocator (e.g. `malloc`) with UM, you should first test the `pageableMemoryAccessUsesHostPageTables` property, as mentioned in that section.

That property currently won't be set on any system except a properly configured IBM Power9 system.  No x86 system currently has this property set/available.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. This is just a very small MCVE that I did in a quick so it was not fancy. However, as mentioned in the last comment in the question, the UM docs say(https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-system-allocator ) *"In the example above, data could be initialized by a third party CPU library, and then directly accessed by the GPU kernel."* which is what I am trying to achieve. I am running on a GTX1070 so I should be OK with the use of UM.

Comment: The data can indeed be **initialized** by a third party CPU library, because managed allocations work like ordinary allocations for the purposes of host code.  However the underlying **allocation** must be one created by the UM system.

Comment: I guess you are referring to section K.1.6 .  Read the comment I made above under the comments on your question.